# Ruby on Rails to check if a variable has a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

My doubt is i am throwing an sql statement

```
@authenticates = Authenticate.find(
  :all, 
  :conditions => ["userid = ? AND password = ?", params[:text1], params[:text2]]
)
```

I need to put an if condition, so that if the above data exists i need to redirect to other page else display an error

How can i do this

Comment: Check the variable your set and change the location you redirect to?

Comment: Also, consider naming your parameters something actually meaningful.

Comment: btw "passwords" that are stored and retrieved like this == open access ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to put an if condition, so that if the above data exists i need to redirect to other page else display an error

Sorry, but your question is awkwardly worded. I would suggest rephrasing the question clearly, so that you can get the right response. I presume what you want is something like this

```
@authenticates = Authenticate.find(
  :all, 
  :conditions => ["userid = ? AND password = ?", params[:text1], params[:text2]]
)
if @authenticates.count < 1
  redirect_to some_action_path
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you need an authentication example. [Check this.](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1)

Otherwise you just need an `if` condition to check if the `@authenticates` variable contains anything or not.

Answer (score 1):

You just want the `if` clause that'll make this happen? If so:

```
if params[:text1] && params[:text2]
  @authenticates = Authenticate.find(
    :all, 
    :conditions => ["userid = ? AND password = ?", params[:text1], params[:text2]]
  )
 else
   redirect_to page_where_the_params_are_set_path
 end
```